# Kotlin Android TextView KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, kotlin

I decided to write small program in Kotlin. And now I have one problem which I can't fix. This is due to NullPointerException. And the Logcat always shows me an error in line where I wrote this `textView_msg!!.text = "${currencyList[p2]}"`. Please help me.

This is my code

```
open class CurrencyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        open var textView_msg: TextView? = null
        open var textView: TextView? = null
        open val currencyList = arrayOf("AUD","CAD","CHF","EUR","GBP","JPY","NZD","KHR","USD","CNY","THB","INR")

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.currency_activty)
            setUpSpinnerData()
        }

        //This method will be invoked to setup data of the spinner views
        //to show lists of currency types for selection
        fun setUpSpinnerData() {
            textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyFrom) as TextView
            textView = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyTo) as TextView

            val spFrom: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.fromCurrency)
            spFrom.onItemSelectedListener = ItemSelectedFrom()
            val afrom: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
            spFrom.adapter = afrom

            val spTo: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.toCurrency)
            spTo.onItemSelectedListener = ItemSelectedTo()
            val ato: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
            spTo.adapter = ato

        }

        class ItemSelectedFrom: CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}

            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                //textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyFrom) as TextView
                textView_msg!!.text = "${currencyList[p2]}"
            }
        }

        class ItemSelectedTo : CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}

            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                //textView = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyTo) as TextView
                textView!!.text = "${currencyList[p2]}"
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: check id name as `setCurrencyFrom` in your xml

Comment: @sushildlh I also tried change this id into another one. But it shows me an error

Comment: Is there any chance that you misspelled `currency_activty`? There is an `i` missing maybe?

Comment: @mTak nope cause when I deleted this class ItemSelectedFrom and change it into `this@MainActivity` everything is working properly

Comment: Is there a layout called `currency_activty` (without the i)? And what did you change to this@MainActivity?

Comment: Do you have instant run enabled?

Comment: @mTak yes this layout without i. I mean this `spFrom.onItemSelectedListener = ItemSelectedFrom()` into this `spFrom.onItemSelectedListener = this@CurrencyActivity` . Sorry not `MainActivity`

Comment: @ReazMurshed no it doesn't enable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I did it. Thanks everybody who tried to help me. I just a little bit rewrite it(but in comments I have an old code). This is my solution.

```
class CurrencyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        var textView_msg: TextView ?= null
        var textView: TextView ?= null

        var currencyList = arrayOf("AUD","CAD","CHF","EUR","GBP","JPY","NZD","KHR","USD","CNY","THB","INR")

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.currency_activty)
            setUpSpinnerData()
        }

        //This method will be invoked to setup data of the spinner views
        //to show lists of currency types for selection
        fun setUpSpinnerData() {

            val spFrom: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.fromCurrency)
            spFrom.onItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener0
            val afrom: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
            spFrom.adapter = afrom

            val spTo: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.toCurrency)
            spTo.onItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener1
            val ato: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
            spTo.adapter = ato

        }

        var onItemSelectedListener0: OnItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.LALALALA)
                Log.e("KUKU", currencyList[position])
                textView_msg?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }

        var onItemSelectedListener1: OnItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                textView = findViewById(R.id.NANANANA)
                textView?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}

        }

    //    class ItemSelectedFrom: CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    //        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    //
    //        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
    //            textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.LALALALA)
    //            Log.e("KUKU", currencyList[position])
    //            textView_msg?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
    //        }
    //    }
    //
    //    class ItemSelectedTo : CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    //        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    //
    //        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
    //            textView = findViewById(R.id.NANANANA)
    //            textView?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
    //        }
    //    }
    }
```

And now what was the problem. Explaining.

```
 var textView_msg: TextView ?= null
// Initialize it somewhere.

textView_msg?.text = "${currencyList[position]}" // Calls setText if textView_msg != null
textView_msg!!.text = "${currencyList[position]}" // Throws an exception if textView_msg == null
```